# Could not apply the stored configuration for monitors - Ubuntu 14.04 Freezes

Tags: 12.04, display, configuration, external-monitor

I downloaded updates to my PC; which was on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS; and the next thing I know it's upgrading Ubuntu.  Now it's upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS; and when I login; it displays the following message:

```
Could not apply the stored configuration for monitors.
None of the selected modes were compatible with the possible modes:
Trying modes for CRTC442
```

Then it lists several different attempts with different resolutions, but then it just freezes, and no longer responds to my mouse clicks. I can't do anything and end up having to shutdown the PC.  I booted up to my bootable Ubuntu 12.04 LTS disk, and used the "Try Ubuntu" option, to see if I could reconfigure the monitor, but no luck. I ended up re-installing 12.04 LTS Desktop, now I can't get it to use any other monitor but "LAPTOP" with a screen resolution of 640x480, and I'm using as my monitor. My TV is an Emerson flatscreen.